# onActivityResult not getting called from other app

Tags: android, android-fragments, onactivityresult, startactivityforresult

I want to start one app from other app and return the result back to calling application.

I've used following code to start activity of other application from fragment.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.putExtra(Constants.KEY_SHOULD_DISPLAY_IMPORT_PROFILE_POPUP, true);
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(oldAppPackageName, "com.activities.MainActivity"));
startActivityForResult(intent, IMPORT_PROFILE_PERMISSION);
```

and used following code in fragment to set result

```
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putSerializable(Constants.KEY_USER_PROFILE, AccountManager.getInstance().getUserProfile());
        bundle.putBoolean(Constants.KEY_IS_FROM_OLD_APP, true)

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra(Constants.KEY_USER_PROFILE_OBJECT, bundle);
        getActivity().setResult(IMPORT_PROFILE_PERMISSION, intent);
        getActivity().finish();
```

But onActivityResult() method is not getting called.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: two application use different task stack ,so in your fragment you can use startActivity() back to calling application

Comment: The first argument in `setResult()` should be `Activity.RESULT_OK`, not the request code.

Comment: onActivityResult() might be returning to host activity onActivityResult() method , but not in fragment , just check it

Comment: @MikeM. it can be also `RESULT_FIRST_USER` and `RESULT_FIRST_USER` + 1 etc and because `RESULT_FIRST_USER` is 1 any positive value is valid

Comment: @pskink Yeah, I guess I half-read their question, and assumed they're checking for `RESULT_OK` in `onActivityResult()`, and that's why they think it's not running.

Comment: @MikeM. agree, i would bet they didnot bother to add `Log.d` in the first line of `onActivityResult`

Comment: @pskink- I have added  log only in onActivityResult().But the method is not getting called.

Comment: @MikeM. Activity.RESULT_OK is also not working

Comment: What's the value of `IMPORT_PROFILE_PERMISSION`? Do you have a `launchMode` attribute specified on the `<activity>` element in the manifest for `MainActivity` in the second app?

Comment: value is IMPORT_PROFILE_PERMISSION is 101 and MainActivity   is  android:launchMode="singleTask"

Comment: hey did you find any solution?